# Java - Display 1and2 3and4... loop with input

Tags: java, loops

I'm new in learning java and programming. Help me to solve this
input : 5
output : 1and2 3and4 5and6 7and8 9and10

Q1 : is it using even/odd correct?
Q2 : is there any other way?
Please help me solve this

I'm thinking using even and odd here. so this what i think so far

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class example3{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int odd = 0;
    int even = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= n; i++) {

        if(i%2==0) {
            even++; 
        } else {
            odd++;
        }
        n--;
    }
    System.out.println(odd+ "and" + even);}
}
```

Comment: what is your problem please?

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Did you try running your program? On my computer, with input 5 it outputs only `1and2`. With input 8 it prints `2and3`. Is this as expected?

Comment: Your test for whether `i` is even or odd is perfect (not everyone gets it right the first time, so congrats).

Comment: If I have understood the assignment correctly, I think I would put a little more arithmetic in it. If with input 5 you loop from 1 through 5 (rather than from 0), you may calculate the odd number as `2 * i - 1` and the even one as `2 * i`. But this is only one way out of many, choose what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on the input and output examples you gave in your question, your problem can be rephrased to this:

> For an input n, print the first n pairs of odd and even numbers

and some code that does this is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int odd = -1;
    int even = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= n; i++) {
        odd = odd + 2;
        even = even + 2;
        System.out.println(odd+ "and" + even);}
    }

}
```

and here is the console upon running it:

`input
5
1and2
3and4
5and6
7and8
9and10`